# Google Earth Engine transforming line region of interest into numpy array

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to get a numpy array from a specific line region with no success.
I have been trying to use [ee.Image.sampleRectangle()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-samplerectangle) but it is sampling only Polygons, and when I use it on Line region, I am getting some unwanted points.
Is there any other function that sample the images?

```
polygon = ee.Geometry.LineString(multicoords[0],ee.Projection('EPSG:32636'))
planarPolygon = ee.Geometry(polygon);

band_arrs = image.sampleRectangle(region=polygon)
band_arrs.getInfo()
band_arr_B8A = band_arrs.get('B8A')
np.array(band_arr_B8A.getInfo())
```

Comment: The problem is that a LineString has no area,

Comment: I know, but still,  ee.Image.sampleRectangle() is sampling an area despite this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reduceRegion with a toList reducer.

```
result = image.reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.toList(), geometry=polygon, scale=..., crs=...)
```

Comment: Hi Thank, it works fine, but somehow if my LineString falls on one pixel I'm not getting any value.

Comment: Either buffer it by 1/4 pixel so it's always at least 1/2 a pixel wide, or use the lineString to mask the original image by painting it into an image:  
    mask = ee.Image().byte().paint(lineString, 1);
    image.updateMask(mask).reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.toList(), geometry=lineString.bounds(), ...`